# Delete FROM Query with Subquery doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I want to delete duplicate entries, where the username is identical, because I inserted by mistake some data twice and I couldn't use the unique field.

I selected first those accounts with a Select Query to make sure, I actually get the right rows which I wanted to delete and this worked fine. Now I wanted to delete them, but I got an error and I dont know why. Here is my query and error:

**Query:**

```
DELETE FROM Gifting
WHERE idGifting NOT IN 
(SELECT MIN(idGifting) FROM Gifting GROUP BY username)
```

**Error:**

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'Gifting' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by using a `join`:

```
DELETE g
    FROM Gifting g LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT MIN(idGifting) as minid
          FROM Gifting
          GROUP BY username
         ) gid
         ON g.id = gid.minid
    WHERE gid.minid IS NULL;
```

This assumes that there are no duplicate ids in `Gifting`.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I will mark it as correct answer once I am allowed to :)